# tableView beginUpdates / endUpdates block reloading entire table even when empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView that periodically gets updated by data coming from a remote service.  I load the data, and store the indexPaths of various data that I just inserted, deleted or updated.  I then have a begin/endUpdates block that completes the necessary operations, as seen below.

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if (pathsToDelete) {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    if (pathsToRefresh) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToRefresh withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToAdd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I noticed recently that cells were being reloaded way more than I was expecting.  Following through in the debugger, I noted that in cases where a single record was being refreshed (ie pathsToRefresh was the only one that had anything, and it had only a single index) the entire table was actually reloading. By that, I mean I was seeing requests to the dataSource for each and every cell in the table.

In debugging, I started stripping things down.  I got all the way to the point where I only had

```
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

And even then, I was seeing the entire table reload (ie cellForRowAtIndexPath was fired for every value in the datasource).  So I assumed something else was happening that I'd missed..but removing those two methods resulted in the reload stopping.

Shouldn't begin/endUpdates do nothing in cases where nothing is within the block?  I'm at a loss on what is actually happening here, as the doc indicates all they do is bookend table operations - and in this case I have none.

Comment: So, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called for each item in your data source?

Answer (score 3):

**objective c iOS reloadRowsAtIndexPaths , reloadSections**

```
if([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1 == -1){

row = 0;

}else{

row = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1 ;

}

NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: (row) inSection: ([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)];

// [self.tableView reloadData];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView endUpdates];



NSLog(@”Number of Sections %ld”, (long)[self.tableView numberOfSections]);

NSLog(@”Number of Rows %ld”, [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)]-1);
```